# Clarification about Power Definition in Optics

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation

I wanted to clarify a concept about units of power used in optics, since I come from an electrical background. I am wondering if the number of photons produced by a light source depends on the wavelength of those photons.

Let's say Light Source 1 produces photons at 800 nm; Light Source 2 produces photons at 400 nm. If both light sources operate at 1 Watt, will Light Source 1 be producing twice as many photons as Light Source 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, watts are watts.

If two sources emit at different wavelengths, it will take a different photon flux to produce the same power.

Comment: Whoa! The photon has answered himself  !! :D